# How can I make RVM respect my bundler's settings on where to put gems?

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

I have my bundler configured to install gems into a `.bundle/` directory inside each project.

```
$ cat ~/.bundle/config
---
BUNDLE_PATH: ".bundle"
BUNDLE_BIN: ".bundle/bin"
```

How can I make RVM respect this setting and not set the `$GEM_HOME` to another directory (inside `~/.rvm/`) whenever I `cd` into my project?

So far I had a [little script](https://github.com/pjg/dotfiles/blob/master/.zshrc#L671-L693) that would set `$GEM_HOME` (and `$PATH` and `$GEM_PATH`) whenever I would `cd` inside my project's directory, but with recent versions of rvm it has stopped working and now RVM basically unsets the Ruby version whenever I manually change `$GEM_HOME` and I have no clue how to make it work again.

Comment: Which is the problem with installing gems into .bundle and running an executable from bin/ folder? For example, I can then run an executable with `bundle exec bin/exec`

Comment: The problem is that RVM sets `$GEM_HOME` to something in `~/.rvm/`, so I cannot do things like `gem cleanup` or `gem install` because the gems are in a different place.

Comment: you can run gem via bundler itself so: `bundle exec gem ...`, so even add an alias `alias gem=bundle exec gem` or get a function to check wheither the bundle is controlling a gem/project folder, and run `gem` or `bundle exec gem` for selected case.

Comment: I don't think you understand. I use the above setup for *all* my projects. I never run `bundle exec` any more.

Comment: What are you using then? `bundle install`, and what else?

Comment: I'm adding ~/bin and ~/bundle/bin to my path, so I have direct access to all gem binaries for any project.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should specify that you want to use the very separate gemset for your project (consider it’s name is *myproject42*):

```
$ cd myproject42 && rvm --rvmrc --create use 2.1.0@myproject42 --ignore-gemsets
```

`rvmrc` option will create the configuration file in your folder. You are already half-separated from the universe. Now you want to modify this file a bit, setting whatever you want:

```
...
unset __hook

# my exports
export GEM_PATH=`pwd`
export GEM_HOME=`pwd`
...
```

`cd` out and back in into this directory. This will result in the warning:

```
You are using '.rvmrc', it requires trusting, it is slower and ...
[LINES SKIPPED]
************************
y[es], n[o], v[iew], c[ancel]> y
Using: /tmp/myproject42
```

Once you confirm you are aware of this modification, the gemset is set to what you wanted (`/tmp/myproject42` in this case.) You may verify that:

```
$ rvm gemset dir
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/tmp/myproject42/bin' is not available,
[LINES SKIPPED]
/tmp/myproject42
```

You might want to make some cleanup, like suppressing those warnings. The “howtos” are printed out inside this warnings, they are pretty straightfoward so I left the description of initial process “dirty” to show it exactly how it would be run on your machine.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but even if it works, it's too much manual work to be done for setting up each new project (i.e. this solution is too cumbersome; it doesn't scale).

Comment: `echo 'export GEM_PATH=.bundler' > .rvmrc` does the trick if you were looking for hacks, like your previous `zsh`-only solution. I described the process how it’s intended to be done with `rvm`.

Comment: mudasobwa provided the answer you asked for. If it's too much work, then script it, or modify RVM. That was a good, informative answer though. That was also a good question. Upvotes for both :)

Comment: I've tried the 'hard' way described in the answer and, unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've commented out my zsh scripts, but RVM won't set correct Ruby if GEM_HOME/GEM_PATH is changed in rvmrc as described and if I use `rvm use 2.1.2` in .rvmrc it sets GEM_HOME/GEM_PATH back to something at ~. I've also tried the quick hack, but it does not work just the same.